# Find the missing word

Tags: word, wordplay

Find words to fit clues.
Each XXX should be replaced with the same three letter word.

_ _ X X X _ _  | Clue - Entertainment

_ _ _ X X X _ | Clue - Continuously attack

_ _ _ X X X _ | Clue - A fruit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that maybe the three-letter word is:

> bar

and the other three words are:

> cabaret
> bombard
> rhubarb  (not a fruit, but...)