# Find the missing words

Tags: wordplay, pattern, letters

<sup>With inspiration from [Detiva's puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97346/find-the-missing-word).</sup>

Find words to fit the clues. Each "X X X" should be replaced with the same three letters.

| Pattern | Clue |
| --- | --- |
| X X X _ _ _ _ | level |
| _ X X X _ _ _ | spread |
| _ _ X X X _ _ | center |
| _ _ _ X X X _ | place |
| _ _ _ _ X X X | language |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the missing letter sequence could be:

> **LAN**

Using the following words:

> **LAN**DING - a *level* of a building between flights of stairs;
>  B**LAN**KET - a *bedspread*;
>  BA**LAN**CE - *center of balance*;
>  IRE**LAN**D (or ICE**LAN**D, ZEA**LAN**D or many others) - a *place*;
>  CATA**LAN** - a *language* most commonly used in parts of Spain.

I had also considered:

> the three-letter sequence **ALI**, since **ALI**GNED (level), RE**ALI**GN (center), SOM**ALI**A (place) and BENG**ALI** (language) all fit, but I could not for the life of me find a satisfying _ALI___ for 'spread'. Then again, it would not surprise me if the OP's intended answer is neither of these but something else altogether!

Comment: For #4 I had in mind rot13(VZCYNAG) (as a verb), but yours are just as good. The other four are exactly what I was thinking of.

Comment: @eyl327 Ah, so this is correct! Glad I abandoned the other one I mentioned then - I was stuck on that one for ages and had to refresh my brain to think up anything else! Crazy how a mind can get fixated on one thing and find it hard to budge... Thanks for the puzzle :)