# Find the missing words #2

Tags: word, wordplay, pattern, letters

<sup>With inspiration from [Detiva's puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97346/find-the-missing-word).</sup>

Find words to fit the clues. Each pair of $\text{X}$'s should be replaced with the same two letters (in order).

$
\begin{gather}
% custom template - reuse if you may
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{19px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\color{white}{\textbf{Pattern}}}\def\NT{\color{white}{\textbf{Clue}}}\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[teal]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2020.01.21-custom}\S{101px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\T&\NT\\\hline
%
~\text{ X _ _ _ _ _ _ X }&\text{ mistake }\\ \hline
~\text{ _ X _ _ _ _ X _ }&\text{ active }\\ \hline
~\text{ _ _ X _ _  X _ _ }&\text{ №1 }\\ \hline
~\text{ _ _ _ X X _ _ _ }&\text{ field }\\ \hline
~\text{ _ _ X _ _  X _ _ }&\text{ direction }\\ \hline
~\text{ _ X _ _ _ _ X _ }&\text{ cut }\\ \hline
~\text{ X _ _ _ _ _ _ X }&\text{ seizure }\\ \hline
\end{array}\end{gather}$

---

The first $\text{X}$ in the first row represents the same letter as the first $\text{X}$ in all other rows and the second $\text{X}$ in the first row represents the same letter as the second $\text{X}$ in all other rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my updated shot at this:

> XX = **IN**
>
>
>  **I**LLUSIO**N** - Mistake
>
>
>  D**I**LIGE**N**T - Active
>
>
>  OR**I**GI**N**AL - No. 1
>
>
>  DOM**IN**ION - Field
>
>
>  GU**I**DA**N**CE - Direction
>
>
>  D**I**SCOU**N**T - Cut
>
>
>  **I**NVASIO**N** - Seizure

Comment: I think you misunderstood the puzzle. It's not *in each row, the two letters are the same*. It's *the same pair of letters in every row*.

Comment: Sorry if the instructions weren't clear. Like in the previous two ([detiva's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97346/find-the-missing-word) and [mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97349/find-the-missing-words)), the same *set* of letters appears on each row. (So the first X in the first row is the same letter as the first X in all other rows and the second X in the first row is the same letter as the second X in all other rows).

Comment: Got it, you can see the reasoning before the edits were included though. Apologies for interpreting a _wordplay_ puzzle clue literally.

Comment: Updated answer to fit the rules

Comment: Re your new answer: There's a typo in your 2nd (9 letters) and your 6th doesn't have enough letters (7 letters)...

Comment: Yep, forgot to update that last one with the shortage. Haste makes waste...

Comment: Your updated answer is correct. For #4, the word I had in mind was rot13("OHFVARFF").